# hg commit says "nothing changed", but hg status -A shows many changed files

Tags: mercurial

I've done some restructuring of my folder structure, and I'm having some issues with mercurial that I'm not sure why is happening.

`hg status` doesn't show any files.

`hg status -A` on the other hand shows a lot of `A somefile` and `R somefile`.

But when I try to commit, `hg` says there are `nothing changed`.

Any idea what is happening here?

I'm running mercurial 2.6, although the repo was created with 2.5.x. I'm also doing this locally.

UPDATE: Any changes on the repo in question gives the same behavior

```
$ echo tmp > tmp
$ hg add tmp
$ hg status # shows nothing
$ hg status -A # shows 'A tmp'Oh, 
$ hg commit
nothing changed
```

UPDATE2: I have the following extensions installed

```
color =
progress =
rebase = 
transplant = 
histedit = 
churn = 
graphlog = 
hgk = 
highlight = 
inotify = 
activity=/home/simendsjo/code/hgactivity-2.1/activity
```

UPDATE3: I didn't have time to investigate this any further, so I just redid my restructuring as before, and this time everything turned out as expected. I didn't do anything other than `hg mv` as I did before though..

Comment: Does this also happen with a brand new repository? Which extensions do you have enabled?

Comment: @shambulator: No, not a new repo. That test is in the repo with the problem just to show that no changes I do is reflected

Comment: Updated my question with the extensions

Comment: Does your configuration ignore "tmp" files? (.hgignore)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': No. A lot of files is marked as Added or Removed, but commit says there are no changes. .hgignore just ignores some other files, and these are reflected as Ignored using hg status -A

Comment: Try disabling the `inotify` extension. You should also post to mercurial@selenic.com where people are better able to help you with any followup debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the inotify extension.  Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and it turned out one of my files and a NULL character in the file name.  It showed up in the HG list of files as a "?" character in the file name.  After renaming it to remove that everything committed like normal.